# How can a reverse proxy be specified in windows?

Tags: networking, proxy

End goal: Intercept HTTP request destined for *xyz.com*, reply with static precomputed response.

I have used mitmproxy before in reverse mode to accomplish this using a web browser but my goal is to target an application running on windows instead.

Would this work with a transparent proxy? Do I just change the gateway address to that of my proxy server?

[Link to mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/doc/mitmproxy.html)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using a program called [ProxyCap](http://www.proxycap.com/). It allows me to redirect certain applications to my proxy server, presumably by intercepting certain function calls.